# Display a specific route in a different router-view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I've got a Vue 3 app with Vue Router 4 and I want to achieve this:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view></router-view> //This is where login would be
    <app-layout>
      <router-view /> //Everything else 
    </app-layout>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import AppLayout from "./components/AppLayout.vue";
</script>
```

I've got an `<app-layout>` component which includes navbar and a sidebar, but I don't want to display those when the user is not logged in. I also don't want to wrap each component in `<app-layout>` individually.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Vue-router's [v-slot API](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view-s-v-slot) like this :

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
            <component v-if="route.name === 'Login'" :is="Component" />
            <app-layout v-else>
                <component :is="Component" />
            </app-layout>
        </router-view>
        <!-- Or -->
        <router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
            <component :is="route.name === 'Login' ? 'template' : 'app-layout'">
                <component :is="Component" />
            </component>
        </router-view>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import AppLayout from "./components/AppLayout.vue";
</script>
```

And in your router, for the `login` route, don't forget to add the route name :

```js
{
    name: 'Login', // important
    // ...
}
```